# Magento: where to find uploaded placeholder images uploaded from admin

Tags: magento

I uploaded three placeholder images from admin (System > Configuration > Catalog > Product Image Placeholders). I've confirmed in the DB (`core_config_data` table) that these settings have applied and I see the previews of these placeholder images in the admin as well.

However, when I navigate to `/skin/frontend/.../images/catalog/product/placeholder`, where `...` is all of the themes there are (base, default, my_theme, etc.), the images are still the default Magento placeholders.

In what directory are the uploaded images stored on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click on the little thumbnail image in the admin and click Properties or Inspect Element (depending on your browser).

On my base CE 1.7.0.2 install, the images are stored here: `/media/catalog/product/placeholder/default/`